# Set Image In an Image View Using JSON Parsing in Android

Tags: android, json, imageurl

I parsed all the textviews and and image in a list view but when i am trying to click on a single list view it does show textview but doesn't show Image view bdw i dont know how to get it.

MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

static ArrayList<Actors> actorsList;

ActorAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    actorsList = new ArrayList<Actors>();
    //final ArrayList<Actors> movieList = new ArrayList<Actors>();
    new JSONAsyncTask().execute("http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/jsonActors");

    ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new ActorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, actorsList);

    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), actorsList.get(position).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  

            Actors m = actorsList.get(position);


            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SingleView.class);
            i.putExtra("position", String.valueOf(position));
            i.putExtra("thumb", m.getImage());
            i.putExtra("name", m.getName());
            i.putExtra("dob", m.getDob());
            i.putExtra("height", m.getHeight());
            i.putExtra("country", m.getCountry());
    //      View imageView = null;
            //imageView.buildDrawingCache();

        //  Bitmap image= imageView.getDrawingCache();

            // Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        //  extras.putParcelable("imagebitmap", image);
        //  i.putExtras(extras);

            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}


class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
        dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {

            //------------------>>
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


                JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("actors");

                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    Actors actor = new Actors();

                    actor.setName(object.getString("name"));
                    actor.setDescription(object.getString("description"));
                    actor.setDob(object.getString("dob"));
                    actor.setCountry(object.getString("country"));
                    actor.setHeight(object.getString("height"));
                    actor.setSpouse(object.getString("spouse"));
                    actor.setChildren(object.getString("children"));
                    actor.setImage(object.getString("image"));

                    actorsList.add(actor);
                }
                return true;
            }

            //------------------>>

        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        dialog.cancel();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if(result == false)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

ActorAdapter.java

```
public class ActorAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Actors> {
ArrayList<Actors> actorList;
LayoutInflater vi;
int Resource;
ViewHolder holder;
private static ActorAdapter mInstance;

public void onCreate() {
    mInstance = this;
}


public ActorAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Actors> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    vi = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    Resource = resource;
    actorList = objects;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // convert view = design
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
        holder.imageview = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
        holder.tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        holder.tvDescription = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDescriptionn);
        holder.tvDOB = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDateOfBirth);
        holder.tvCountry = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvCountry);
        holder.tvHeight = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvHeight);
        holder.tvSpouse = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvSpouse);
        holder.tvChildren = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvChildren);
        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }
    holder.imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    new DownloadImageTask(holder.imageview).execute(actorList.get(position).getImage());
    holder.tvName.setText(actorList.get(position).getName());
    holder.tvDescription.setText(actorList.get(position).getDescription());
    holder.tvDOB.setText("B'day: " + actorList.get(position).getDob());
    holder.tvCountry.setText(actorList.get(position).getCountry());
    holder.tvHeight.setText("Height: " + actorList.get(position).getHeight());
    holder.tvSpouse.setText("Spouse: " + actorList.get(position).getSpouse());
    holder.tvChildren.setText("Children: " + actorList.get(position).getChildren());
    return v;

}

static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageview;
    public TextView tvName;
    public TextView tvDescription;
    public TextView tvDOB;
    public TextView tvCountry;
    public TextView tvHeight;
    public TextView tvSpouse;
    public TextView tvChildren;

}

 class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }


}

public static ActorAdapter getInstance() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mInstance;
}
```

SingleView.Java

```
public class SingleView extends Activity{
TextView name,dob,height,country;
Button back,prev,nxt;
ImageView img ;

//imageLoader = ActorAdapter.getInstance().getImage();

private ArrayList<Actors> movieList_detail = new ArrayList<Actors>();

int selected = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.singleview);    

    Intent i = getIntent();

    final String image1 = i.getStringExtra("thumb");
    String name1 = i.getStringExtra("name");
    String dob1 = i.getStringExtra("dob");
    String height1 = i.getStringExtra("height");
    String country1 = i.getStringExtra("country");

    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
    name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    dob = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDateOfBirth);
    height = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvHeight);
    country = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvCountry);
    back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    prev = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    nxt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

    movieList_detail = MainActivity.actorsList;


    name.setText(name1);
    dob.setText(dob1);
    height.setText(height1);
    country.setText(country1);



    back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
        }
    });

    prev.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(selected>0){

                selected--;

                Actors m = movieList_detail.get(selected);
                //String image  = m.getThumbnailUrl();
                name.setText(m.getName());
                dob.setText(m.getDob());
                height.setText(m.getHeight());
                country.setText(m.getCountry());
            //  img.DisplayImage(m.getImage(), image1);


                nxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else
            {
                prev.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });

        nxt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(selected<5){

                    selected++;

                    Actors m = movieList_detail.get(selected);
                    //String image  = m.getThumbnailUrl();
                    name.setText(m.getName());
                    dob.setText(m.getDob());
                    height.setText(m.getHeight());
                    country.setText(m.getCountry());
                //  imageLoader.DisplayImage(m.getImage(), img);

            prev.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else
            {
                nxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });


}
```

}

```
Actors.java

public class Actors {
private String name;
private String description;
private String dob;
private String country;
private String height;
private String spouse;
private String children;
private String image;

public Actors() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Actors(String name, String description, String dob, String country,
        String height, String spouse, String children, String image) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.dob = dob;
    this.country = country;
    this.height = height;
    this.spouse = spouse;
    this.children = children;
    this.image = image;
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getDob() {
    return dob;
}

public void setDob(String dob) {
    this.dob = dob;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

public String getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public void setHeight(String height) {
    this.height = height;
}

public String getSpouse() {
    return spouse;
}

public void setSpouse(String spouse) {
    this.spouse = spouse;
}

public String getChildren() {
    return children;
}

public void setChildren(String children) {
    this.children = children;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}
```

}

Comment: Your question is not clear, I saw your MainActivity where in listing you are loading image in ActorAdapter. But in your single view Activity you are not loading image. So how will it display image??? If you want you can use Glide or Picasso image loading library.

Comment: Dear @Sudhanshu you are putting image url in intent of SingleViewActivity , and you need to run your image downloader task to set image on image view in SingleViewActivity.

Comment: Thats what i am asking Neeraj how to set image in singleview.java class , i passed through intent and got it from MainActivity and set All the textviews but not able to set the imageview couldn't find a proper solution for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this**

```
public class SingleView extends Activity{
TextView name,dob,height,country;
Button back,prev,nxt;
ImageView img ;

//imageLoader = ActorAdapter.getInstance().getImage();

private ArrayList<Actors> movieList_detail = new ArrayList<Actors>();

int selected = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.singleview);    

    Intent i = getIntent();

    final String image1 = i.getStringExtra("thumb");
    String name1 = i.getStringExtra("name");
    String dob1 = i.getStringExtra("dob");
    String height1 = i.getStringExtra("height");
    String country1 = i.getStringExtra("country");

    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
    name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    dob = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDateOfBirth);
    height = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvHeight);
    country = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvCountry);
    back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    prev = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    nxt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

    movieList_detail = MainActivity.actorsList;


    name.setText(name1);
    dob.setText(dob1);
    height.setText(height1);
    country.setText(country1);

new DownloadImageTask(img).execute(image1);


    back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
        }
    });

    prev.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(selected>0){

                selected--;

                Actors m = movieList_detail.get(selected);
                //String image  = m.getThumbnailUrl();
                name.setText(m.getName());
                dob.setText(m.getDob());
                height.setText(m.getHeight());
                country.setText(m.getCountry());
            //  img.DisplayImage(m.getImage(), image1);


                nxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else
            {
                prev.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });

        nxt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(selected<5){

                    selected++;

                    Actors m = movieList_detail.get(selected);
                    //String image  = m.getThumbnailUrl();
                    name.setText(m.getName());
                    dob.setText(m.getDob());
                    height.setText(m.getHeight());
                    country.setText(m.getCountry());
                //  imageLoader.DisplayImage(m.getImage(), img);

            prev.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else
            {
                nxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });


}
```

Comment: I just used it(new DownloadImageTask(img).execute(image1);) and got an error on "DownloadImageTask" that to make a class named as "DownloadImageTask"..:(.

Comment: You need to create  DownloadImageTask as stand alone so that you can utilize in both SingleViewActivity and in ActorAdapter or other vise you can copy paste  DownloadImageTask class in SingleViewActivity from ActorAdapter

Comment: Done boss thank you boss :) now i can see image in imageview but one more thing please help me to show image after clicking the next and previous button too. See i can see image when i clicked on a particular listview but after i clicked on next button the image remain same please give me the vode for it

Comment: Yurekkkaaaaa:)..boss thank you so much i just put the same code in previous and next button and also get the image.I would like to vote your answer but i dont have reputation so cant able to do it sorry..

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the image is not visible in SingleView Activity.

img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivImage);

Next you are setting values for

```
    name.setText(name1);
dob.setText(dob1);
height.setText(height1);
country.setText(country1);
```

You missed loading imgae in img.
Do take a look at Picasso for image loading lib

Comment: Thanks for the answer vab but i didnt miss it ,i really dont know how to set image in it because see to show a text we have to setText like this to show image what we have to do and how i dont know so please let me know if you know something about it?

Comment: To set the image you need the image. Either you can save the image path from first download, downlad it again or cache it using Lru cache.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion vab let me try it and let you know after doing it.